# Python: How to iterate through a group of files and grep for logs after the specified date and time

Tags: python, datetime

I am given a task of collecting the logs from 10 text files which are,
a,a.0,a.1 .... a.9. These logs need to be collected from a specified date and time which is passed as an argument. The big question is I know how to find the date and logs after that, but how do I repeat the same for 10 text files at the same time. The collected logs are saved in a text file again.

So far, I have tried this:

```
month_abbr = {"jan": 1, "feb": 2, "mar": 3, "apr": 4, "may": 5, "jun": 6,
              "jul": 7, "aug": 8, "sep": 9, "oct": 10, "nov": 11, "dec": 12}

min_val = "Aug 14 15:35:54"
print min_val


def parse_date(lines):
    mon, day, tim = lines.split(None, 3)[:-1]

    date_string = "{:02} {:02} ".format(month_abbr[mon.lower()], int(day)) + tim
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    except ValueError as e:
        return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d %H:%M:%S")


def threshold(min_val):
    mon, day, tim = min_val.split(None, 3)
    date_string = "{:02} {:02} ".format(month_abbr[mon.lower()], int(day)) + tim
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    except ValueError as e:
        return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d %H:%M:%S")


command = ' grep -i error /var/log/a | grep -i a0 '

sub_proc1 = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=lambda: signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL))

result = sub_proc1.communicate()[0]
timestamp = open("temp.txt", "w+")
timestamp.write(result)
timestamp.close()
f = open("temp.txt")

for lines in f:
    date_string = " ".join(lines.split(None, 3)[:-1])
    #print(date_string)
    date_object = parse_date(lines)
    #print(date_object)
    if parse_date(lines) >= threshold(min_val):
        print(lines)
```

Please note: Only Standard Python Libraries can be used !

Comment: You don't really need to call command from shell (like `grep`). Simply use `os.path.listdir` to iterate through the `/var/log/` directory and just print necessary data from files with specified name.

Comment: Also why you use two similar functions `parse_date` and `threshold`? You can set `min_value` to `datetime.strptime("8 14 15:35:54", "%m %d %H:%M:%S")` at the beginning. Or if you need it `datetime.strptime(f"{month_abbr['Aug']} 14 15:35:54", "%m %d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: why not just use grep? this program doesn't do anything that can't be accomplished from the shell with the `grep` and `date` programs.

Comment: There is a rest of other stuff also the program needs to do, that's why need to write it in a program @M

Answer (score 0):

So, here is my solution:

```
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime

MONTHS = {month: i for i, month in enumerate(['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun',
                                              'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov',  'dec'])}
LOG_DIR = '/var/log'


def parse_date(s):
    try:
        month, rest = s.split(None, 1)
    except ValueError:
        return None

    date = MONTHS[month.lower()] + ' {rest}'

    try:
        return datetime.strptime(date, "%m %d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        return datetime.strptime(date, "%m %d %H:%M:%S")
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return None


if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print('Usage: <start> <end>', file=sys.stderr)
    exit(1)

start, end = sys.argv[1:]

for filename in os.listdir(os.path.join(LOG_DIR)):
    name, *_ = filename.rsplit('.')
    date = parse_date(name)
    if date and parse_date(start) <= date <= parse_date(end):
        with open(os.path.join(LOG_DIR, filename)) as f, open(output, 'a') as out:
            for line in f:
                print(line)
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but I am getting this error                                                       date = f'{MONTHS[month.lower()]} {rest}'
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: And I need to program using python 2.6 !

Comment: @SarahHarvey fixed.